# getting cannot rollback - no transaction when using slqite for laravel testing

Tags: laravel, sqlite, database-migration, bdd, behat

I'm trying to use in memory sqllite for my laravel testing, by putting this in my .env file:

```
'sqlite_testing' => [
    'driver'   => 'sqlite',
    'database' => ':memory:',
    'prefix'   => '',
]
```

(it's in my .env.testing file, which is the same env specified in my phpunit.xml).

However I keep on getting this error (even if I so much as run this command):

```
php artisan --env=testing  migrate
```

I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 cannot rollback - no transaction is active (SQL: rollback)
```

I searched [online](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/25957/#Comment_25957) and found that this may have to do with sqlite opening many connections at the same time and not closing them first. But I'm not sure how to address that problem with laravel.

## Note

unlike all the hello world tutorials that talk about using sqlite, my situation is that I have an enterprise application that has hundreds of migration files, and I'm trying to introduce unit testing to the development workflow. I'm using [behat](https://github.com/Behat/Behat) for BDD and for some reason using [RefreshDatabase](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) makes it hang after running each scenario. So I'm trying to find a more lighter weight database to be able to do that.

Comment: Have you tried using a file database instead of the :memory driver?

Comment: no, that would defeat the purpose won't it @dparoli? I might as well just use a testing psql db

Comment: Did you "clear your configuration cache using the `config:clear` Artisan command before running your tests"?

Comment: I guess you are using "use DatabaseTransactions" in your testing. I guess you need to build your own DatabaseMigration, I had the same situation, I was working on a project with more than 120 migrations and when I wanted to run the tests using DatabaseMigration trait it was taking so much time, so I have forced to use DatabaseTransactions trait but that cause me a lot of other problems, for example, it's not working smoothly with the DB::transaction so eventually I have made my way to run the migrations which it makes it very fast now I run 1600 test less than 8 min.. I can also share the way.